# error in simple mac os , xcode web browser : NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1022

Tags: xcode, macos-high-sierra

I have created a simple web browser in xcode for macos, using this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oKk4zSTHzwY

but when i type https://google.com
I get following error in xcode console : NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1022

Comment: -1022 = `NSURLErrorAppTransportSecurityRequiresSecureConnection`

Comment: how to fix this

Comment: BTW, you can't expect us to watch the video to figure out what you did. You should edit your question, removing the video link and replace it with a [small code snippet that can reproduce your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You generally fix -1022 error by adding "allow arbitrary loads" setting under "app transport security settings" category in one's info.plist.